# Elasticsearch - Use a bool query inside nested_filte of sort

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-2.0, elasticsearch-query

I have a query that filters out products which have a special price from a quantity of 5. Now I want to order the products descending by price. As the price per piece is higher for the quantity of one it should not be taken into account. I read that I can filter in the sort with nested_filter but when just copy pasting the query it is not working.
Below is a short version where only the most important query part is shown.

```
{
  "sort": [
    {
      "prices.netPrice": {
        "order": "desc",
        "nested_filter": {
           //TODO: What comes here?
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "should": [
            {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "nested": {
                      "path": "prices",
                      "query": {
                        "term": {
                          "prices.quantity": 5
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```